# Not able to connect Node.js server using Socket.Io.Client from Xamarin.Android client

Tags: c#, node.js, xamarin, socket.io, xamarin.android

I am trying to implement Socket.Io client in my chat application using Xamarin Android.
For validation I am using my physical device. In debug, noticed Socket gets connect only once I launch and for rest of the times it gives java.Lang.Object error when reopen the app background. Also this works one time when I uninstall and reinstall again in the device. Please suggest to fix this.

Below steps have been followed to setup :

1. Set the IOOptions inside onCerate method.
2. OnResume checking the socket and closing and opening
3. Used android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"  in Manifest file
4. Validating with API level 29

Your help would be greatly appreciated

**Server Side(Node.js) Implementation:**

```
var port =0000;
var app = require('express')();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var concurents = {};

var fs = require('fs');

var pkey = fs.readFileSync('ssl/xyz.pem');
var pcert = fs.readFileSync('ssl/abc.pem');

var options = {key: pkey,cert: pcert};
var http = require('https').Server(options, app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http,{transports: ['websocket'],  upgradeTimeout: 10000,  
allowUpgrades: false,  pingTimeout: 10000,  pingInterval:5000,  });
```

**Client Side(Android) Implementation:**

OnCreate:

```
IOOption = new IO.Options()
        {
            Query = "key=xxxxx&domain=xxxxx&origin=xxxxx",
            Reconnection = true,
            Timeout = 60000,
            ReconnectionDelay = 1000,
            ReconnectionAttempts = 999999999,
            ForceNew = true,
            Secure = true,
            Upgrade = false,
            Host = "111.xxx.xxx.xxx",
            Hostname = "xxxxx",
            Port = xxxx,
            Transports = new string[1] { WebSocket.TransportName }
        };
```

onResume:

```
    if (socket != null)
        socket.Close();
    
    socket = IO.Socket("https://domain:port", IOOption);

    socket.On(Socket.EventConnect, (data) =>
            {
                socket.Emit("connect_user", 123);
                AttachSocketEvents(socket);
            });
            socket.On(Socket.EventConnectError, (data)=> {
                Console.WriteLine("Connection failed");
            });
            socket.On(Socket.EventConnecting, (data) => {
                Console.WriteLine("Connecting failed");
            });
            socket.On(Socket.EventError, (data) => {
                Console.WriteLine("EventError failed");
            });
           socket.Connect();
```

Comment: Does `io.on('connection')` work when your app is run? Can you confirm that on the server? Can the device access the server? Have you tried on an emulator? Was there a difference?

Comment: @jegtugado Yes,  io.on('connection') works when app is running.  When running on emulator its not connect at all.

Comment: Where is your socket io server hosted? Is it on your local machine? If yes, is it accessible within the network? You say the connection works for the first time, when does the connection get cut-off?

Comment: @jegtugado it is not hosted in local machine. Its running in production. This works once, when I uninstall and reinstall again in the device.